# Photoshop tools list popout

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Is it possible to "popout" this menu so that it doesn't collapse again when I click away. I want to be able to rapidly switch tools when I'm painting without having to open the menu again. Like how you're able to keep the brush presets tab open without it closing when you actually paint on the canvas? Maybe there's an addon/extension or something I can use to achieve this?

[image: The menu I want to permanently popout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose `Window > Tool Presets` and a panel will open. It will operate like any other panel.